# How to set low to high in tablesorter as default ?

Tags: javascript, tablesorter

I'm using tablesorter jquery (**jquery.tablesorter.js**) to sort table information in my page. and ***it's working well***.

I added an ID to table to sort data like this:

```
<table id="keywords">
```

and I used following script function to sort data based on table:

```
$(function(){
$('#keywords').tablesorter(); 
});
```

But I need to click on table thead that data will be sorted.

Here is my question:

**> How to set Low to High based on numbers in table columns as DEFAULT ?**

For example: when we open page, then table information will be sorted automatically based on Low to High (Default). but if we click on Table thead then it will be sorted accordingly.

Thanks in advance

Comment: if you are populating table from database you can update your query so that it can get data in orderly way you want.

Answer (score 1):

In your JavaScript you can initialize order of specific columns. You can add multiple columns using comma separtor.

Below is example for single column.

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    // call the tablesorter plugin 
    $("yourtable").tablesorter({ 
        // sort on the first column, order asc 
        sortList: [[0,0]] 
    }); 
});
```

Below is example for Multiple column.

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    // call the tablesorter plugin 
    $("yourtable").tablesorter({ 
        // sort on the first column and third column, order asc 
        sortList: [[0,0],[2,0]] 
    }); 
});
```

There is one more way of doing it by sorting order with metadata in the markup

```
<table class="tablesorter {sortlist: [[0,0],[4,0]]}" cellspacing="1">
```

For reference:

[Set a initial sorting order](http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-option-sort-list.html)

[Sorting order with metadata](http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-meta-sort-list.html)

Comment: Note: If you plan on using metadata, you will need the jQuery plugin: https://github.com/jquery-archive/jquery-metadata

Comment: @Mottie Thanks for adding that up.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to sort data automatically as default based on columns, we can use following code:

```
 sortList: [[5,0]]
```

Based on number of columns, if we have for example: one table wih 10 columns, but we want to sort low to high only for **column 6** from left to right, then we can use above sortlist in script, and if we have two columns, we can sort them like this: [[0,0],[1,0]]

Comment: "and if we have two tables, we can sort them like this: [[0,0],[1,0]]" how is that possible? two tables? do you mean two columns?

Comment: Yes that's right, two columns, but if you want to sort two different tables with different columns, you can use  $(".table1").tablesorter for table 1, and   $(".table2").tablesorter for table 2, then sort them by     sortList: [[0,0],[1,0]] as mentioned in above.